# Wrong path with PHP in WordPress

Tags: php, wordpress

I've a problem with the path of a contact form template in Wordpress. I have `contact-form.php` then I have a directory called `contact`, inside there are `contactform.js` and `mailer.php`

Everything works well if I use the standard permalink
[image: standard permalink]

Instead if I use a different kind of permalink as example
[image: not standard permalink]

The `contactform.js` have to load an image `loader.gif` and `mailer.php`

```
$(document).ready(function() {

    //click of form bottom
    $("#contact-button").click(function(){
        $(this).hide(); 
        $("<img src='wp-content/themes/twentyeleven/images/loader.gif' class='loader' />").appendTo("#contact");




$.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: "wp-content/themes/twentyeleven/contact-form/mailer.php",
```

When I use different I have in the console developer of google chrome, I shouldn't have `contattaci` in the path.
[image: errors]

I'd like to use a not standard permalink as in the second image, how can I do?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is the path that are wrong, you can try to use the full path (of the image) of the website or use a div with a background  setted with the css.

You have tried to add a / at the start of the path?

Comment: ok, I haven't tried to write full path, but if I want do so, I have to change the code and I should check how to write correctly. DO you know?

Comment: `<?php bloginfo('template_url'); ?>` read here http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/bloginfo

Comment: For the image I've solved putting ../wp-content/path/path... (2 points and slash before the path). Now I have to solve also the mailer.php hope in the same way

Comment: With this solution if you use standard permalink you'll get error, but for me is ok so ;)

Answer (score 1):

The problem is with your SRC code.
when you are in a page like: `http://domain.com/page` and you call a link from the path `wp-content/themes/twentyeleven/images/loader.gif` you get the url you are in now + the link path.
which means you get:

`http://domain.com/page/wp-content/themes/twentyeleven/images/loader.gif`

while the real link is supposed to be:

`http://domain.com/wp-content/themes/twentyeleven/images/loader.gif`

if this is a function in a php file i recommend you to change it to this:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    //click of form bottom
    $("#contact-button").click(function(){
        $(this).hide(); 
        $("<img src='<?php bloginfo('template_url'); ?>/images/loader.gif' class='loader' />").appendTo("#contact");
    }
}
```

you can find this function at: [Function Reference/bloginfo](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/bloginfo)

Comment: I have http://domain.com/page/contact, well for the image I must have http://domain.com/page/wp-content/themes/twentyeleven/images/loader.gif and with your code that I had alreayd tried the result is http://domain.com/page/contact/wp-content/themes/twentyeleven/images/loader.gif and so I get error.

Comment: have you tried my code? the link it returns is:
`http://domain.com/wp-conent/themes/tamplatename`

Comment: Yes but it doesn't work. I have as result http://domain.com/home/contattaci/%3C?php%20bloginfo(

Comment: for the php code to run, the file must be a .php file... can you change it?

Comment: no isn't possible because the javascript give the start to mailer.php

Comment: so a php script is nothing we can use... you can use this code in javascript: `if (!window.location.origin) window.location.origin = window.location.protocol+"//"+window.location.host;`. this will return the base url. and that you add the rest of the directorys info.